# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug, process exception return code 1

Tags: android, runtimeexception, dex, processexception

My project was running good on another PC. But unable to run here.
Firstly, play repository was not updated. After completing update, build was successful but can't run.

**app level build.gradle-**

[image: app level build.gradle]

**project level build.gradle-**

[image: project level build.gradle]

**getting error-**

[image: error]

How can I get rid from this problem?

This question is similar to many like [this](http://Error:Execution%20failed%20for%20task%20':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug') but exception is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It might be due to multiple libraries compilation, This might solve the problem

```
  android{
defaultConfig {

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}


dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
    }
     dependencies {
//...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  }
```